# How to pre-populate username in MSAL .NET IPublicApplication sing-in?

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to pre-prepopulate username when using MSAL.NET for signing in?
This is to avoid MSAL prompting for username and only ask for password and 2FA info if required.

Our application already 'knows' a username before it launches MSAL signing-in.

Client app creation:

```
    app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                    .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
                    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                    .WithLogging(Log, Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Info, true)
                    .Build();
    TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(PublicClientApp.UserTokenCache);
```

User sign-in:

```
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
```

Also tried the following but MSAL still prompted for account name:

```
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithLoginHint("username@domain.com") // <= existing account name provided here
                .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: I think at least you can't use `PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)`  to realize it, as the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplicationoptions?view=azure-dotnet#properties) don't provide such property.